# Embed resources from a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I'm making an app with custom visual design. My plan is to reuse the custom design elements for other future apps as well, so I thought the use of a resource dictionary in a separate file would be a good idea.

Somewhere in the resource dictionary file I have some BitmapImage objects for use in various controls.

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="xIconClose" CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource="C:\_x\source\Refs\EpicStyle\IMG\Frame\xCross.png"/>
<BitmapImage x:Key="xCheckboxChecked" CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource="C:\_x\source\Refs\EpicStyle\IMG\xCheckbox_checked.png"/>
<BitmapImage x:Key="xCheckboxUnchecked" CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource="C:\_x\source\Refs\EpicStyle\IMG\xCheckbox_unchecked.png"/>
<BitmapImage x:Key="xHeaderBTNMask" CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource="C:\_x\source\Refs\EpicStyle\IMG\Frame\HeaderBTN.png"/>
```

The question is, how do I embed these linked image files in the built application?

Currently, when I build the application and the try to run it, it still uses the files from those locations. I would like to have a result where all the needed files are either embedded in the exe or somehow packed in some other resource file that would come with the built exe.

How would I do that for files defined in a resource dictionary?

Comment: You may load the BitmapImages from assembly resource files. That would however require to have a class library project where the resource files reside. Add the image files to such a project, set their Build Action to Resource and load them by `UriSource="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/FileName.png`, where AssemblyName is the assembly name of the class library, Images the name of a project folder, and FileName the name of an image file in the project. See [Pack URIs in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

Comment: Thank you. This works. If you would write this as an answer, I will accept it.